# paypal, show the result of the operation

Tags: php, paypal

I made a payment button that works with paypal.
everything works, but I do not know how to show the outcome of the operation to the user.
I am using this code in the "notify_url": https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php
On this page I can handle errors and deciding on the message to be displayed on the page of "return" but as a step this error from the page of "notify_url" to that of "return"?
Thanks.

ps: I tried ocn the $ _SESSION but it does not work.

Comment: `return` is the variable that you need to use so that you can display an custom message on the payment completion page. what is the issue you face when you use return ?

Comment: return is the veriabile with the URL of the landing page. but in this page, if I var_dump the POST & GET not see anything

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly print `POST` and `GET` in return variable, you will need to use [PDT or IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/) to get/retrieve the transaction and related information back.

If you want to get back the information instantly upon completion of payment, use PDT.
If you want to get back the additional information upon payment completion, more recommended and reliable go for IPN..

Comment: I'm doing some research but can not find a sample code. 
in the file ipn.php I can read all the information and handle errors, but then I can not find a way to show them to you.